# Cannot call org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.JpaSort#path()

Tags: spring-data-jpa

When I have below entity

```
@Entity
class Article {

  String title;

  @OneToMany
  List<Comment> comments;
}
```

and try to create `JpaSort`, like below.

```
Sort sort = new JpaSort(Article_.title)
  .and(Sort.Direction.ASC, JpaSort.path(Article_.comments).dot(Comment_.author));
```

But above code can't be compiled, because of `ambiguous method call`.
How can I call this method for `PluralAttribute` ?

I read [official test code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/JpaSortTests.java#L157), but this block was commented out.

Comment: Someone issued a bug for this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2089